# How to count duplicate values in the list object in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, count

in java, i have an array like this:

```
String[] city = {"texas", "ny", "sydney", "ny", "paris", "texas", "ny"};
```

i want to sort/group them with count...like-

```
texas = 2
ny = 3
sydney = 1
paris = 1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Comment: Try `Map<String,Integer>`.

Answer (score 10):

Use `Collections.frequency()` method.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] city = {"texas", "ny", "sydney", "ny", "paris", "texas", "ny"};
        List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(city);
        Map<String, Integer> map= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(String s: city){
            map.put(s,Collections.frequency(asList,s));
        }
        System.out.println(map);

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `Collections#frequency(java.util.Collection, Object)`